# Labview optimization VIs

Tags: labview

I am trying to minimize a specific spectral coefficient in respect to a set of parameters involved in my array, using the global optimization VI, and the process gets stuck. Maybe I am using the wrong VI I don't know. Here are screenshots of my code:
[image]

and the sub-VI that's referenced:
[image]

Basically it averages an array (which values are a linear function of three parameters) over one dimension then gets a certain coefficient of its power spectrum, after that the main VI tries to minimize that coefficient in respect to the three aforementioned parameters. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please clarify what's wrong with your current code or what you don't like about the NI global optimization VI? If it's literally hanging, then what happens when you try it with a smaller input? Are you sure it's not just taking a long time?

Comment: Did you try debugging the sub VI? Is the Objective funtions returning any meaningful value? How much time is needed for one execution?

Comment: @Charlie I have unfortunately moved on from this subject :-/